# Can I have a C# generic constraint on "operator true"?

Tags: c#, boolean, operator-overloading

Let's say I have a class that contains a list of booleans, and I want a property that reports if they are all 'true'.  There are a couple ways to do this:

```
class BunchOfBools
{
    List<bool> Stuff = new List<bool>();
    bool AllAreTrue1 => Stuff.All(b => b);
    bool AllAreTrue2 => Stuff.TrueForAll(b => b);
}
```

Cool.  Life is good.

But now I realize I have a class that implements "operator true" and "operator false"

```
class BatteryIsGood
{
   float BatteryVoltage;

   public static bool operator true(BatteryIsGood ab) => ab.BatteryVoltage >= 3;
   public static bool operator false(BatteryIsGood ab) => ab.BatteryVoltage < 3;
}
```

And if I have a bunch of "BatteryIsGood" objects (yeah, this is a contrived example) and I want to use BunchOfBools to check if they are all good - so make BunchOfBools generic:

```
class BunchOfBools<T>
{
    List<T> Stuff = new List<T>();
    bool AllAreTrue1 => Stuff.All(b => b);
    bool AllAreTrue2 => Stuff.TrueForAll(b => b);
    bool AllAreTrue3 => Stuff.All(b => (bool)b);
    bool AllAreTrue4 => Stuff.TrueForAll(b => (bool)b);
    bool AllAreTrue5
    {
        get
        {
            foreach (T one in Stuff)
            {
                if (!one)
                    return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
    bool AllAreTrue6 => Stuff.All(b => (bool)(object)b);
    bool AllAreTrue7 => Stuff.TrueForAll(b => (bool)(object)b);
}

BunchOfBools<BatteryIsGood> allBatteriesAreGood;
```

But of course the compiler is not at all happy with the generic BunchOfBools (Functions 1 through 5 don't compile) because "cannot convert type 'T' to bool".  AllAreTrue6 and AllAreTrue7 compile but are (1) ugly, (2) inefficient, and (3) not typesafe (you won't find out until runtime that 'T' can't convert to bool).

Is there a way to add a generic constraint that says "T has to implement operator true"?

EDIT

It's even reasonable to say the class has to implement an implicit conversion to bool, if that helps:

```
class BatteryIsGood
{
   float BatteryVoltage;

   public static bool operator true(BatteryIsGood ab) => (bool)ab;
   public static bool operator false(BatteryIsGood ab) => !((bool)ab);

   public static implicit operator bool(BatteryIsGood big) => ab.BatteryVoltage >= 3;
}
```

Comment: May not be the most elegant, but answer works right?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of ToString and Parse, like the following:

```
class BunchOfBools<T>
{
    List<T> Stuff = new List<T>();
    bool AllAreTrue1 => Stuff.All(b => bool.Parse(b.ToString()));
    bool AllAreTrue2 => Stuff.TrueForAll(b => bool.Parse(b.ToString()));
    bool AllAreTrue3 => Stuff.All(b => (bool)bool.Parse(b.ToString()));
    bool AllAreTrue4 => Stuff.TrueForAll(b => (bool)bool.Parse(b.ToString()));
    bool AllAreTrue5
    {
        get
        {
            foreach (T one in Stuff)
            {
                if (!bool.Parse(one.ToString()))
                    return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
    bool AllAreTrue6 => Stuff.All(b => (bool)(object)b);
    bool AllAreTrue7 => Stuff.TrueForAll(b => (bool)(object)b);
}
```

Comment: There are a couple of problems here - (1) you are now requiring that "ToString" return exactly "true" or "false".  Since T could be an arbitrarily complex object, that might not be reasonable.  (2) you still don't have compile-time safety - you won't know until you access the property whether T is meeting your needs or not.

Comment: Oh well - Guess them is the breaks.